Issues with FastAPI Uvicorn workers | Only one worker is handling the request
I have a sample FastAPI application, with a single endpoint which returns the result a after a delay of 5 seconds.
Please find the code below.
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn, os, time
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/delayed-response")
async def read_root():
    time.sleep(5)
    return {"message": f"This is a delayed response!- {os.getpid()}"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=9090,
        reload=False,
        workers=10, #Just having 10 workers to understand the concept.
    )

Now I also have a script that will be sending parallel requests to the endpoint http://localhost:9090/delayed-response
Upon starting the Application I came to know that all 10 workers with process id from 9 to 18 are started successfully.

When I send 20 parallel request to this endpoint I observe that only first few requests are handled parallel by the workers and later only one worker is handling all the remaining requests. (May be from a certain point).
Attaching few screenshots of the response:-


Can anyone explain this behavior?

When sudden requests are being sent to an endpoint, why is the first set of requests are handled in parallel (which is equal to the number of workers) later only one worker starts handling the requests?
Is it a behaviour of the FastAPI or Uvicorn?

Note: Let us consider this application to be a synchronous application. I understand that there are few concepts to make is work in a concurrent way, but at this point I wish to understand this working.
My Expectation : My expectation is that when 10 workers are configured and 30 requests are sent in parallel, the 30th request to an endpoint with 5s delay should get the response at ~15th to 17th second.

My guess is that, when a worker becomes available, requests start getting assigned to it one by one. This happens faster than the time it takes for a worker to get flagged as busy. (This seems like a bug. Shouldn't the act of assigning a request make the worker busy?) Maybe adding worker_class="uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker" to .run would help.

Thanks for you reply @Ouroborus I have also tried the same. Not directly in Code.
But using the command in Docker Image that I had built.
CMD ["poetry", "run","gunicorn", "main:app", "-w", "10", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:9090", "--timeout","600"]

I would expect what you do, 30 requests with 10 workers should complete in ~15 seconds.

"Gunicorn relies on the operating system to provide all of the load balancing when handling requests." - I'm guessing you're hitting the issues that's being tracked in https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/2938 and described in https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2465 and https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/2101

You might find this answer helpful as well.

When lots of requests come in faster than the workers can handle, some requests might have to wait in line. This waiting can happen because of things like not enough resources or too many requests trying to use the same resources at once. In your situation, since your app processes requests one after the other, this waiting might be happening because each request takes time to finish before the next one can start. So, if too many requests come in at once, they'll start stacking up, and eventually, only one worker will be left to handle them all.

Yeah, If too many requests comes in, Requests will be stacked.
But how only one worker will be left to handle all of them?
Let us say that if we have 10 workers configured and 15 requests are coming in, At first 5 seconds all the 10 workers will be busy and in the next 5 seconds any of the 5 workers will be handling the requests and the remaining 5 will be set as free right?
Why does the last few are handled by only one worker? :-(
Kindly correct me if I have any wrong understanding @protoak.

My doubt is like the internal load balancer of Uvicorn should share the load across the remaining free workers right?

That's what I'd expect, it looks like workers are terminating for some reason?

@David Waterworth, If the workers are terminating I would have seen them in the logs.
Unluckily, I am not able to find any such logs.

@Nandha Imagine you have 10 workers ready to handle requests, but suddenly 15 requests come in. At first, all 10 workers start working on the incoming requests. After a while, some workers finish their tasks and become free. But if the requests take longer than 5 seconds each, those workers stay busy until they're done. This means that even after the first batch of requests is handled, some workers might still be tied up with earlier ones.

Now, if more requests keep pouring in while some workers are still busy, those new requests have to wait until a worker is available. Because there might not be enough free workers to handle all the incoming requests, they start lining up and waiting for their turn. If this queue keeps growing and all the workers are occupied, the next available worker takes on the new requests. This can lead to a situation where only one worker is handling all the requests, while the others are either still busy with earlier ones or sitting idle.

Uvicorn's internal load balancer usually spreads incoming requests among the workers. But sometimes, things might not work exactly as planned. It could be because of how requests are lining up, how busy the workers are, or how the settings are configured. Checking these things can you help figure out why this is happening.

Note that you're mixing an async handler (async def read_root), with a blocking (synchronous) call to time sleep.
Fastapi can handle blocking requests via its internal threadpool, but to do so, you need to define a regular handler (def read_root).
If you have an async handler, you should  use:
await asyncio.sleep(5) instead
See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups
And here:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#in-a-hurry
